# What's the significance of the old photo of a plane at the end of "Mirror Image"?

Tags: quantum-leap

On the series finale "Mirror Image", after Sam's final leap, slow music plays in a reminiscing fashion and a black-and-white photograph of an old plane on a field is shown (possibly a biplane). The photo featured an old man and possibly a kid, I can't remember for sure.  I was very puzzled at the time about what it meant and have never found any reliable explanation.

I speculated at the time that it might have been intended to be a young Sam with his father, but there was no biplane in the episode "The Leap Home". More recently, I saw some chat site suggesting it was a photo of a young Donald P. Bellisario with his own father, but no references were given.

Is there an official answer?

Comment: It's probably a reference to [the final scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G62tkd2t7qk) of the iconic 1942 movie classic, [*Casablanca.*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0034583/)

Comment: Internet chatter suggests that it's a picture of the showrunner and his father, on whom the character is based; http://quantumleap-alsplace.com/forum/showthread.php?t=1994

Comment: And per [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0681144/trivia): *""Al the Bartender" was modeled after Donald P. Bellisario's father Albert Bellisario. The photographs in the bar are of Al Bellisario, and the photograph under the end credits is of Al Bellisario holding a young Donald at an air show in Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania.*"

Comment: They knew this was the final episode (if not at filming, at least with enough time to make some last minute changes like the "Sam Becket has never returned home" end card), so it certainly makes sense for Bellisario to do it as a personal "dedication" rather than making it have some in-universe meaning.